# FIrestore: Finding large files or directories

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a few hundred folders in my Firestorage bucket, each containing a couple of small images. However, my storage size is almost 80GB!

Is there a way to find the culprit files or folder? I can't seem to find a way to view folder sizes or get a list of the top largest files without causes a huge number of reads.

Comment: What are you using to store the files? A Cloud Storage Bucket, Firestore, Firestore with Cloud Storage or Firebase with Cloud Storage? Basically, I'm trying to find out if you can see the buckets if you go to console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser

Comment: Hi @OliverAragon, I'm using Firestore to store the files with a Flutter app. I am able to view the files if I go to console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the gsutil command, you could try using the [DU command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du):

gsutil du -sh YOUR_BUCKET/YOUR_DIRECTORY

The -s flag will give you only the size of the directory, if you remove it you will also see the size of the files inside. 
The -h flag prints object sizes in human-readable format (e.g., 1 KiB, 234 MiB, 2GiB, etc.)

You can then find out which files are the biggest.